# When submitting a place order button to order page that time generate this message

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, php-5.5, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.7

**When submitting a place order button to order page that time generate this message.
How to resolve this error. Please help any one.**

Order Object ( [id_address_delivery] => 88641 [id_address_invoice] => 88641 [id_shop_group] => 5 [id_shop] => 1 [id_cart] => 31973 [id_currency] => 1 [id_lang] => 1 [id_customer] => 27026 [id_carrier] => 73 [current_state] => [secure_key] => 353b960ec14efca0bf8145f79908794a [payment] => Authorize.net AIM (Advanced Integration Method) [module] => authorizeaim [conversion_rate] => 1.000000 [recyclable] => 0 [gift] => 0 [gift_message] => [mobile_theme] => 0 [shipping_number] => [total_discounts] => 0 [total_discounts_tax_incl] => 0 [total_discounts_tax_excl] => 0 [total_paid] => 6.5 [total_paid_tax_incl] => 6.5 [total_paid_tax_excl] => 6.5 [total_paid_real] => 0 [total_products] => 6.5 [total_products_wt] => 6.5 [total_shipping] => 0 [total_shipping_tax_incl] => 0 [total_shipping_tax_excl] => 0 [carrier_tax_rate] => 0 [hazmat_fees] => 0 [poison_fees] => 0 [refrigerated_fees] => 0 [ponumber] => [total_wrapping] => 0 [total_wrapping_tax_incl] => 0 [total_wrapping_tax_excl] => 0 [invoice_number] => [delivery_number] => [invoice_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [delivery_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [valid] => [date_add] => [date_upd] => [reference] => JYADOFQPY [webserviceParameters:protected] => Array ( [objectMethods] => Array ( [add] => addWs ) [objectNodeName] => order [objectsNodeName] => orders [fields] => Array ( [id_address_delivery] => Array ( [xlink_resource] => addresses ) [id_address_invoice] => Array ( [xlink_resource] => addresses ) [id_cart] => Array ( [xlink_resource] => carts ) [id_currency] => Array ( [xlink_resource] => currencies ) [id_lang] => Array ( [xlink_resource] => languages ) [id_customer] => Array ( [xlink_resource] => customers ) [id_carrier] => Array ( [xlink_resource] => carriers ) [current_state] => Array ( [xlink_resource] => order_states ) [module] => Array ( [required] => 1 ) [invoice_number] => Array ( ) [invoice_date] => Array ( ) [delivery_number] => Array ( ) [delivery_date] => Array ( ) [valid] => Array ( ) [date_add] => Array ( ) [date_upd] => Array ( ) ) [associations] => Array ( [order_rows] => Array ( [resource] => order_row [setter] => [virtual_entity] => 1 [fields] => Array ( [id] => Array ( ) [product_id] => Array ( [required] => 1 ) [product_attribute_id] => Array ( [required] => 1 ) [product_quantity] => Array ( [required] => 1 ) [product_name] => Array ( [setter] => ) [product_price] => Array ( [setter] => ) [unit_price_tax_incl] => Array ( [setter] => ) [unit_price_tax_excl] => Array ( [setter] => ) ) ) ) ) [_taxCalculationMethod:protected] => 1 [id] => [id_shop_list] => [get_shop_from_context:protected] => 1 [table:protected] => orders [identifier:protected] => id_order [fieldsRequired:protected] => Array ( [0] => id_address_delivery [1] => id_address_invoice [2] => id_cart [3] => id_currency [4] => id_lang [5] => id_customer [6] => id_carrier [7] => payment [8] => module [9] => total_paid [10] => total_paid_real [11] => total_products [12] => total_products_wt [13] => conversion_rate ) [fieldsSize:protected] => Array ( ) [fieldsValidate:protected] => Array ( [id_address_delivery] => isUnsignedId [id_address_invoice] => isUnsignedId [id_cart] => isUnsignedId [id_currency] => isUnsignedId [id_shop_group] => isUnsignedId [id_shop] => isUnsignedId [id_lang] => isUnsignedId [id_customer] => isUnsignedId [id_carrier] => isUnsignedId [current_state] => isUnsignedId [secure_key] => isMd5 [payment] => isGenericName [module] => isModuleName [recyclable] => isBool [gift] => isBool [gift_message] => isMessage [mobile_theme] => isBool [total_discounts] => isPrice [total_discounts_tax_incl] => isPrice [total_discounts_tax_excl] => isPrice [total_paid] => isPrice [total_paid_tax_incl] => isPrice [total_paid_tax_excl] => isPrice [total_paid_real] => isPrice [total_products] => isPrice [total_products_wt] => isPrice [total_shipping] => isPrice [total_shipping_tax_incl] => isPrice [total_shipping_tax_excl] => isPrice [carrier_tax_rate] => isFloat [hazmat_fees] => isPrice [poison_fees] => isPrice [refrigerated_fees] => isPrice [total_wrapping] => isPrice [total_wrapping_tax_incl] => isPrice [total_wrapping_tax_excl] => isPrice [shipping_number] => isTrackingNumber [conversion_rate] => isFloat [date_add] => isDate [date_upd] => isDate ) [fieldsRequiredLang:protected] => Array ( ) [fieldsSizeLang:protected] => Array ( ) [fieldsValidateLang:protected] => Array ( ) [tables:protected] => Array ( ) [image_dir:protected] => [image_format:protected] => jpg [def:protected] => Array ( [table] => orders [primary] => id_order [fields] => Array ( [id_address_delivery] => Array ( [type] => 1 [validate] => isUnsignedId [required] => 1 ) [id_address_invoice] => Array ( [type] => 1 [validate] => isUnsignedId [required] => 1 ) [id_cart] => Array ( [type] => 1 [validate] => isUnsignedId [required] => 1 ) [id_currency] => Array ( [type] => 1 [validate] => isUnsignedId [required] => 1 ) [id_shop_group] => Array ( [type] => 1 [validate] => isUnsignedId ) [id_shop] => Array ( [type] => 1 [validate] => isUnsignedId ) [id_lang] => Array ( [type] => 1 [validate] => isUnsignedId [required] => 1 ) [id_customer] => Array ( [type] => 1 [validate] => isUnsignedId [required] => 1 ) [id_carrier] => Array ( [type] => 1 [validate] => isUnsignedId [required] => 1 ) [current_state] => Array ( [type] => 1 [validate] => isUnsignedId ) [secure_key] => Array ( [type] => 3 [validate] => isMd5 ) [payment] => Array ( [type] => 3 [validate] => isGenericName [required] => 1 ) [module] => Array ( [type] => 3 [validate] => isModuleName [required] => 1 ) [recyclable] => Array ( [type] => 2 [validate] => isBool ) [gift] => Array ( [type] => 2 [validate] => isBool ) [gift_message] => Array ( [type] => 3 [validate] => isMessage ) [mobile_theme] => Array ( [type] => 2 [validate] => isBool ) [total_discounts] => Array ( [type] => 4 [validate] => isPrice ) [total_discounts_tax_incl] => Array ( [type] => 4 [validate] => isPrice ) [total_discounts_tax_excl] => Array ( [type] => 4 [validate] => isPrice ) [total_paid] => Array ( [type] => 4 [validate] => isPrice [required] => 1 ) [total_paid_tax_incl] => Array ( [type] => 4 [validate] => isPrice ) [total_paid_tax_excl] => Array ( [type] => 4 [validate] => isPrice ) [total_paid_real] => Array ( [type] => 4 [validate] => isPrice [required] => 1 ) [total_products] => Array ( [type] => 4 [validate] => isPrice [required] => 1 ) [total_products_wt] => Array ( [type] => 4 [validate] => isPrice [required] => 1 ) [total_shipping] => Array ( [type] => 4 [validate] => isPrice ) [total_shipping_tax_incl] => Array ( [type] => 4 [validate] => isPrice ) [total_shipping_tax_excl] => Array ( [type] => 4 [validate] => isPrice ) [carrier_tax_rate] => Array ( [type] => 4 [validate] => isFloat ) [hazmat_fees] => Array ( [type] => 4 [validate] => isPrice ) [poison_fees] => Array ( [type] => 4 [validate] => isPrice ) [refrigerated_fees] => Array ( [type] => 4 [validate] => isPrice ) [ponumber] => Array ( [type] => 3 ) [total_wrapping] => Array ( [type] => 4 [validate] => isPrice ) [total_wrapping_tax_incl] => Array ( [type] => 4 [validate] => isPrice ) [total_wrapping_tax_excl] => Array ( [type] => 4 [validate] => isPrice ) [shipping_number] => Array ( [type] => 3 [validate] => isTrackingNumber ) [conversion_rate] => Array ( [type] => 4 [validate] => isFloat [required] => 1 ) [invoice_number] => Array ( [type] => 1 ) [delivery_number] => Array ( [type] => 1 ) [invoice_date] => Array ( [type] => 5 ) [delivery_date] => Array ( [type] => 5 ) [valid] => Array ( [type] => 2 ) [reference] => Array ( [type] => 3 ) [date_add] => Array ( [type] => 5 [validate] => isDate ) [date_upd] => Array ( [type] => 5 [validate] => isDate ) ) [classname] => Order ) [update_fields:protected] => [product_list] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [hazmat_fees] => 0 [poison_pack] => 0 [refrigerated_fees] => 0 [drop_shipping] => 0 [id_product_attribute] => 0 [id_product] => 21930 [cart_quantity] => 1 [id_shop] => 1 [name] => Hot/cold Protective Mitt, 17" Length [is_virtual] => 0 [description_short] =>
• For extreme hot or cold applications
• Cotton coated with aluminized silicones
• Withstands 450°F in short int

[available_now] => [available_later] => [id_category_default] => 1181 [id_supplier] => 0 [id_manufacturer] => 0 [on_sale] => 0 [ecotax] => 0.000000 [additional_shipping_cost] => 0.00 [available_for_order] => 1 [price] => 6.5 [active] => 1 [unity] => [unit_price_ratio] => 0.000000 [quantity_available] => 106 [width] => 8.000000 [height] => 8.000000 [depth] => 8.000000 [out_of_stock] => 2 [weight] => 1.000000 [date_add] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [date_upd] => 2016-09-01 08:00:39 [quantity] => 1 [link_rewrite] => HOTCOLD-PROTECTIVE-MITT-17-LENGTH [category] => chemical-and-heat-gloves [unique_id] => 0000021930000000000088641 [id_address_delivery] => 88641 [wholesale_price] => 4.214648 [advanced_stock_management] => 0 [supplier_reference] => [id_customization] => [customization_quantity] => [reference] => 180-50591 [ean13] => [upc] => [minimal_quantity] => 1 [stock_quantity] => 106 [price_wt] => 6.5 [total_wt] => 6.5 [total] => 6.5 [id_image] => 21930-71813 [legend] => [reduction_applies] => [quantity_discount_applies] => [allow_oosp] => 1 [features] => Array ( ) [rate] => 0 [tax_name] => [warehouse_list] => Array ( [0] => ) [in_stock] => 1 [carrier_list] => Array ( [0] => 73 ) ) ) )

Answer (score 3):

This is the ggetto order, this message appears in the presence of a:

```
var_dump ($ order);
```

in any file should appear that function.